# Minimum specifications for bootable external drive

Tags: usb, external-disk, thunderbolt

I’d like to buy an external drive around a terabyte and install macOS on it so that I can travel with just the drive and use my family’s computer as needed.

I want something that is small, portable, and fast. Ideally the size of a USB-C stick, but larger is acceptable.

What is the best option for a drive that can achieve good performance when connected to a new Mac that has thunderbolt 4? Does the drive need to support thunderbolt 3 to work well or will traditional USB 3.1 be enough?

Comment: Where to begin? How about a gigabyte is not nearly enough to hold macOS? Also, newer Macs by default are prevented from external drive booting.

Comment: I meant to say a terabyte, thanks for pointing it out. And silicon Macs can definitely boot from external drives.

Comment: Could you read [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437022/can-apple-silicon-based-mac-boot-from-unauthorized-external-drive) and possibly comment?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a 1TB 'thumb'-size drive.

Comment: The answer there is the word “unauthorized”, I’m obviously authorized on my own laptop.