# Will an external NVME drive at 2700 MB/s work on macOS?

Tags: ssd, thunderbolt, bootable-disk

I’m looking to buy a [Samsung 980 pro](https://a.co/d/cDY58Qr) NVMe M.2 and sticking it in an [ACASIS enclosure](https://a.co/d/6K7LVZf). It should get 2700 MB/s read and write.

I’m wondering if that will be fast enough to boot and run macOS purely from the external drive in a manner that is comfortably fast enough to get normal work (browsing the web, typing word documents, watching YouTube) done.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please check your URLs as they are unreachable and malformed.

Comment: What model of Mac? TBH, I would expect much lower speeds to be 'comfortably fast' for light usage like that.

Comment: I agree with @benwiggy. I have an old external SSD that tops out at 300MB/s write and 400MB/s read and I run multiple OSes from that drive with no problems whatsoever. Also not sure what this ACASIS enclosure is, but you need 2.7GB/s = more than 20GBit/s for the connection...

Comment: That’s probably because I copied them from the Amazon app so while they do link directly back to the app, they may not work in other circumstances, I’ll see what I can do to fix them.

Comment: It’s a thunderbolt 3 enclosure working with a high speed NVME SSD. What I’d like to do is just get a USB stick, but I’m just not sure that that would actually work.

Comment: @benwiggy: The OP's [previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448690/minimum-specifications-for-bootable-external-drive) (which you have already commented on) suggests use would be with different Macs.

Comment: The goal would primarily be for use on a 16 inch MacBook Pro, but one significant benefit would be the ability to also plug it into like a 13 inch MacBook Air. I would assume most of the computers I would use it with have thunderbolt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a 2018 Mac mini with a 500 GB Samsung X5 external Thunderbolt 3 drive. According to the website [Samsung X5 Overview](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/portable-ssd/x5/), this drive has read/write speeds of 2,800/2,300 MB/s when used with a Dell Alienware System (Dee i7 Alienware 17 R5). The table below shows the differences between the Dell and my Mac.

|  | Dell Alienware System (Dee i7 Alienware 17 R5) | 2018 Apple Mac mini |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OS | Windows 10 x64 | macOS Mojave |
| CPU | Intel® Core™ i7 8570H(@4.1GHz) | Intel® Core™ i5 8500B(@3.0GHz) |
| Memory | 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4 | 8 GB 2667 MHz DDR4 |

So while I do not know the read/write speeds for my Mac, I would assume the speeds are slightly less than 2,800/2,300 MB/s. Under normal usage, I do not notice any significant difference between running macOS from the internal drive and from the Samsung X5 external drive.

You state in your question read/write speeds of 2700/2700 MB/s. The website [Things you should know before buying ACASIS 40Gbps NVMe SSD Enclosure (TBU401)](https://www.acasis.com/blogs/shopping-guide/things-you-should-know-before-buying-acasis-usb-4-0-enclosure-tbu401) has a table, which is repeated below.

> Note: For a better view, click on the image or open the image in a new window.

[image: read/write]

Be aware that no read/write speeds in the table are as high as 2700/2700 MB/s. However, the speeds are on the same order as the Samsung X5 specification of 2,800/2,300 MB/s. ***Therefore, I would assume an external drive constructed from the combination of the Samsung 980 Pro and this ACASIS enclosure would be fast enough for your needs.***

There are also the following advantages to this combination over an all-in-one drive such as the Samsung X5.

- **Price:** A 1TB Samsung 980 Pro costs 130 USD and the ACASIS enclosure costs 140 USD, for a total price of 270 USD. Where as a [1 TB Samsung X5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GBWZJFG) costs 500 USD.
- **Replacement:** If the external drive combination fails due to use, you only have to replace the internal drive and not the ACASIS enclosure. Where as with the all-in-one Samsung X5, you can not reuse the Thunderbolt interface.
- **Compatibility:** The ACASIS enclosure works with older USB ports. The Samsung X5 is Thunderbolt only.

Comment: I got this exact set up and it’s been working great!