# Bootable External Drive Issue on Apple Silicon M2- Need Help Resolving

Tags: mac, restore, apple-silicon, carbon-copy-cloner, superduper

I've been encountering difficulties with my bootable external drive on my Apple Silicon M2.I can boot Successfully on M1 mac. I've tried creating the bootable drive using ASR, Carbon Copy Cloner, and SuperDuper, but unfortunately, the system doesn't boot up, displaying an error message indicating that the OS needs to be reinstalled on the selected disk.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Checked compatibility:
Ensured macOS version on the external drive is compatible with Apple Silicon.
Recreated the bootable drive:
Used ASR, Carbon Copy Cloner, and SuperDuper to recreate the bootable external drive.

Reset NVRAM/PRAM:
Attempted to resolve the issue by resetting NVRAM/PRAM.

Checked external drive connection:
Ensured proper connection and tried different ports and cables.

Checked for errors:
Ran Disk Utility from Recovery Mode to check and repair any disk-related issues.

Despite these efforts, the problem persists.

The external drive is formatted with the APFS file system, and I've verified that the cloning tools are up to date.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions from the community on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue.

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem with bootable external drives on Apple Silicon, and if so, how did you successfully address it?

I have tried Monterey, Ventura and Sonama as well.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: You didn't say what macOS. The requirements for minimum OS will be different.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I have added OS in Questions.
Tried Monterey, Ventura and Sonama as well.

Comment: I wonder whether this might have something to do with it -  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437022/can-apple-silicon-based-mac-boot-from-unauthorized-external-drive